# Architecture abstraction problem in Repository ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, data-modeling, repository-pattern

I'm working with MVC ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 on VS2008.
I'm looking for a way to abstract this three methods I have in my Users repository.

```
public User GetUser(Log log)
{
  return db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Logs.Any(l => l.id.Equals(log.id)));
}

public User GetUser(Product product)
{
  return db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Products.Any(pr => pr.id.Equals(product.id)));
}

public User GetUser(Photo photo)
{
  return db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Photos.Any(ph => ph.id.Equals(photo.id)));
}
```

My DB.edmx contains the models

```
User    [id, username, ...]  
Product [id, name, ...]
Photo   [id, name, ...]
Log     [id, data, ...]
```

Is it possible to have only **ONE** method for all of these (and future) methods based upon model.id search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public User GetUser(Expression<Func<User, bool>> restriction)
{
  return db.Users.Where(restriction).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Now use it:

```
var u = Repository.GetUser(u => u.Logs.Any(l => l.id.Equals(log.id)));
```

You can also use MS [DynamicQuery](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx):

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

//...
public User GetUser(string propertyName, int id)
{
    var restriction = propertyName + ".Any(id = @0)";
    return db.Users.Where(restriction, id).FirstOrDefault();
}

var u = Repository.GetUser("Logs", log.id);
```

I may not have the syntax quite correct, but you get the idea.

Comment: Great. But I need a "more automated" expression, maybe using the class name.

Comment: Then use MS Dynamic LINQ to do the same thing. I'll update the example.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll try the last one you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If all the associated entities (Log, Product and Photo) will be searched by a common property (id INT) then maybe you could try something like this...

First, create an interface:

```
public interface IUserAssociation
{
    int id { get; }
}
```

Then each of the three classes would implement this interface like so:

```
public partial class Product : IUserAssociation
{
}
```

The the GetUser method would look like so:

```
public User GetUser<T>(T entity) where T : IUserAssociation
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    if (type == typeof(Log))
    {
        return db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Logs.Any(l => l.id.Equals(entity.id)));
    }
    else if (type == typeof(Product))
    {
        return db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Products.Any(pr => pr.id.Equals(entity.id)));
    }
    else if (type == typeof(Photo))
    {
        return db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Photos.Any(ph => ph.id.Equals(entity.id)));
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to call GetUser and pass it a Log, Photo or Product entity from one method. It is not very elegant but would work for this specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

I like Craig's solution better but I'd suggest this:

```
Repository.GetUser(u => u.Logs, log);
```

Which will be possible if all your entities derive from

```
public interface IEntity { public int Id { get; } }
```

Then method will be like

```
public User GetUser<T, Y>(Func<T, IList<Y>> getlist, Y sample)
   where T: IEntity
   where Y: IEntity
{
  return db.Users.Select(x => getlist(x).Any(y => y.Id == sample.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Also if we take idea of S#arp Architecture that if entity1.Id == entity2.Id (for persistent entities) then Equals(entity1, entity2) - we can use getlist(x).Contains(sample).